# Copy file(s) from one docker container to another – from within the source container

Tags: docker

I have two containers, `foo` and `bar`, that are networked together. `foo` has files on it that I want to copy to `bar`. However, due to circumstances beyond my control I am only able to run commands from within `foo`'s shell and using the docker cli is off the table. I am also unable to control how the containers are initialized. How can I copy files from `foo` to `bar` within `foo`?

Comment: If volumes s an option and you have access to the code itself you can write from foo the the volume and bar can read from there. Also , although I would recommend against you can expose a port n the target and work with ssh or something of this sort, but like I mentioned I would recommend against as it.

Comment: I guess you can't as you even do not have access for `bar`.